# Initialise a Glide carousel inside a modal launched with Alpine.js

Tags: modal-dialog, alpine.js, glidejs

I've forked a Codepen I found on how to launch multiple modals using Alpine.js: https://codepen.io/tyssen/pen/wvQqYLZ

I've adapted a bit because I want to display a Glide carousel as part of the modal content. As you'll see in the Codepen above, I've got the images displaying but the carousel isn't initialised. I don't really know where to start with that.

All the code is in the pen but I'll include it here so it's a bit easier to read:

```html
    <div x-data="{}">
      <div class="button" @click="$dispatch('modal', {articleSearch: 1, isOpen: true,  url: './one.html'})">
        Product One
      </div>
    </div>
    <div x-data="{}">
      <div class="button" @click="$dispatch('modal', {articleSearch: 2, isOpen: true, url: './two.html'})">
        Product Two
      </div>
    </div>
    <div x-data="{}">
      <div class="button" @click="$dispatch('modal', {articleSearch: 3, isOpen: true,  url: './three.html'})">
        Product Three
      </div>
    </div>

    <div x-data="articleSearch()">

      <template x-on:modal.window="articleSearch = $event.detail.articleSearch; url = $event.detail.url; isOpen = $event.detail.isOpen; fetchArticle();"></template>
      <template x-if="article">
        <div class="modal-overlay" x-show="isOpen" x-cloak>
          <div class="modal-container" x-show="isOpen" @click.away="closeArticle();" x-cloak>

            <div class="modal-head">
              <div class="article-attributes">
                <span x-text="'Product ' + article.id"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="close" @click="closeArticle();"><i class="fas fa-times">X</i></div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
              <h3 x-text="article.title"></h3>
              <p x-text="article.description"></p>

              <div class="glide glide-project">
                <div class="glide__track" data-glide-el="track">
                  <ul class="glide__slides glide-fade h-full">
                    <template x-for="image in article.images">
                      <li>
                        <img :src="image" alt="">
                      </li>
                    </template>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </template>

    </div>
```

```javascript
    function articleSearch() {
      return {
        isLoading: false,
        isOpen: false,
        articleSearch: 0,
        url: "",
        article: null,
        fetchArticle() {
          this.isLoading = true;

          fetch(`https://dummyjson.com/products/${this.articleSearch}`)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
              // console.log(data);
              this.isLoading = false;
              this.article = data;

              window.history.pushState("", "", this.url);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.log("ERROR", err));
        },
        closeArticle() {
          window.history.back();
          this.isOpen = false;
          this.articleSearch = 0;
          this.url = "";
          this.article = null;
        }
      };
    }
```

I've got other Glide carousels elsewhere on the site not in modals which work fine. They're initiliased from a script that is added at the bottom of the document and deferred:

```javascript
    import Alpine from 'alpinejs';
    import Glide, {
      Autoplay,
      Breakpoints,
      Controls,
      Swipe,
    } from '@glidejs/glide/dist/glide.modular.esm';

    window.Alpine = Alpine;
    window.Alpine.start();
    window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

      const hero = new Glide('.glide-hero', {
        type: 'carousel',
        perView: 1,
        autoplay: 3000
      });

      if (document.querySelector('.glide-hero')) {
        hero.mount({ Autoplay, Controls, Swipe });
      }

    });
```

I've tried moving the `articleSearch` function to this script instead of being inline on the page, but when I do that, I get errors about `articleSearch` and `article` not being defined. I don't understand why that is.

I know that if I try and initialise Glide carousels from the script in the page itself like the `articleSearch` function is, that it will throw errors due to Glide not being loaded until the script at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Since you're building new HTML (using `template`) you'll most likely have to mount your Glide again, after the images are built.

Comment: Yeah I thought that would be the case, but if I try and mount it inside the `template` I get Glide is not defined because it's not defined until the deferred script at the bottom of the page.